# Target MDN's nightly build as CFX's default browser

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, plugins

I am developing on a Ubuntu system a Firefox extension. For my situation, I want to easily test my extensions against the latest "nightly-build" from MDN.

Following these 3 steps (From: [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion))

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install firefox-trunk`

In the shell-prompt, if I execute the SDK test suite (`cfx testall`) the old firefox browser is called.

So after unsuccessfully trying:

- `cfx -a firefox-trunk testall`
- Set the nightly-build browser as the default browser (i.e. *nightly-build* > *firefox* > *chrome*)

Would somebody happen to know a good work around?

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials) is an excellent reference point for all mozilla add-on development

Answer (score 1):

The nearest alternative was to add the Mozilla Team's PPA repository key to the package manager. In Ubuntu, it is done as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
```

Note: It will replace your system's stable Firefox with the beta copy (*as denoted by 'next')*